# vue.js 2 && webpack-simple && style-loader

Tags: webpack, vue.js

Стоит шаблон **webpack-simple**, хочу подключить css путем:

```
import 'my-package/lib/theme-default/index.css'
```

в webpack.config.js добавил:

```
{
          test: /\.css$/,
          loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'  
},
```

при запуске пишет, что не найден модуль style-loader:

```
ERROR in ./src/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style-loader' in ....
```

подскажите как его поставить, видел есть еще какой-то vue-style-loader.
просто установил **npm install vue-style-loader --save** - ничего не дало

Comment: спасибо, все получилось!

Comment: сделал коммент ответом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что надо поставить сам style-loader а не vue style loader. то есть выполнить команду `npm install style-loader --save-dev`

И нужен вам он только на этапе препроцессинга, поэтому `--save-dev` а не `--save`